# Touch listener on framelayout and scrollview on inflated layout issue

Tags: android, scrollview, ontouchlistener, android-framelayout, gestures

I am doing a flip card application in which i have applied onTouchListener on my frame layout. By using singletap gesturelistener i am flipping card from front to back and vice versa. Every thing is working fine. As my data is large i have to introduce scroll view on my inflated layouts.

```
setContentView(R.layout.flashframe);
cardView = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
    cardView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mGestureDetector=new GestureDetector(this.getBaseContext(), new MyGestureListener(this));
    if(savedInstanceState==null){
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new CardFrontFragment()).commit();
        cardNumber=1;
        setCard(cardNumber);
    }
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}
 public class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    public MyGestureListener(OpenClass openClass) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
            @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent me)
    {
        flipCard();
        return true;
    }
    }
```

XML Layout :-

```
   <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView android:layout_weight="30" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="To be retrieved from sqlite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"       android:layout_height="match_parent"></TextView>
        </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Frame Layout:-

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

When i am inflating my layout with scroll view, gesture listener is not responding whereas scroll view is working on front card. I am unnable to flip, if i am using scroll view.

Please help me, how i can solve this..

Comment: Post your layout xml

Comment: @Chadi Abou Sleiman--I have posted my xml layout.

Comment: Where is your frame layout??

Comment: @Chadi Abou Sleiman--posted

Comment: Which one is the complete `R.layout.flashframe` xml?

Comment: @Chadi Abou Sleiman-- flashframe is my framelayout which i have posted. I am adding layouts in framelayout dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You should override the ScrollView's onTouchListener. In it you can check whenever to flip your card or scroll...

Comment: Here is an example: http://techin-android.blogspot.in/2011/11/swipe-event-in-android-scrollview.html